# RQT main window configuration

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I gonna to use RQT main window with plugins written by myself. I wonder if it is possible to remove menu bar from RQT main window without recompiling or not?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268072/rqt-main-window-configuration/) by [a.alexeev3](https://answers.ros.org/users/31446/a.alexeev3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try these options out:

```
 -f, --freeze-layout   freeze the layout of the GUI (prevent 
                       rearranging
                        widgets, disable undock/redock)

-l, --lock-perspective
                        lock the GUI to the used perspective
                        (hide menu bar
                        and close buttons of plugins)
```

(Though when I try `rqt -l` now with the latest kinetic, lunar, and kinetic-devel qt_gui_core I still see File and Help. That must be a regression, [I took a screenshot a few months ago](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/pull/82) where File and Help are gone)

This is in the [kinetic-devel branch of qt_gui_core](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core):

```
-ht, --hide-title     hide the title label, the icon, 
                        and the help button
                        (combine with -l and -f to 
                        eliminate the entire title
                        bar and reclaim the space)
```

It hides the title bars of individual plugins.

If you clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core.git into your catkin_ws it will overlay the system installed qt_gui_core.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0